# Should you use PUT or POST when an authenticated user is trying to update their own settings?

Tags: api, api-design, http

An example of my API is

```
mydomain.com/v1/update-profile
```

So the user is authenticated and wants to update some stuff in their profile. Should we design the API to expect a POST or a PUT HTTP Method?

From my internet search it seems PUT is idempotent, but at the same time it's usually used for updating a particular *resource* in a URL with an id at the end. Example:

```
mydomain.com/v1/questions/{id}
```

Comment: Do you consider this operation a *replacement* of the original resource (the profile), or merely an *edit?* If you're following REST semantics, and it's an edit, then a PATCH seems more appropriate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request

Comment: This is a very frequently asked question.You need to be more specific than "stuff" to get a good answer. Please post an example containing a data model or interface YAML.

Answer (score 4):

Is the update a rewrite or an append?

If I update my profile by adding 1 word to it, such that applying this 100 times gives me a profile with 100 words then this is not [idempotent](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html) and should be a POST.

If applying this 100 times gives me the same 1 word profile every time then it is idempotent and could be a PUT.

> Idempotence is an important concept in the HTTP specification that states idempotent HTTP requests will result in the same state on the server no matter how many times that same request is executed. GET, HEAD, PUT, and DELETE all have this attribute, but POST does not.
>
> [stormpath.com - to put or post](https://stormpath.com/blog/put-or-post)

Comment: Is this _your_ rule or more like an accepted standard?

Comment: @Aganju better?

Comment: Wasn't a critic, I liked the rule, but didn't want to embrace it before I know if it's a general thing. Thanks!

Comment: @Aganju You're the best kind of critic. The kind that helps me improve the answer.

Comment: The article calls out *You can use POST to send either all available values or just a subset of available values*. IMO this doesn't demarcate when to use PUT and POST for updates

Comment: @user7 - the idea is, use `PUT` for updates when you want to *completely* replace the resource's state with whatever you are `PUT`ting. Use `POST` when you want to either create a new resource, OR you want to partially replace resource state.  Note that `PATCH` was supposed to be the verb that would return balance to the force in that it would replace the second usage of `POST` -  to partially replace resource state  - but for some reason it doesn't seem to have gotten that famous even though I use it all the time :)

Comment: @StephenByrne `PATCH` isn't very clear. RFC 5789 doesn't actually say how it should work, just having `[description of changes]` in the only example they provide. There are a bunch of different views on how those changes should be described ranging from "just don't include fields you want to leave alone" to formats that have a list of operations (`[{"op": "set", "field": "firstname", "value": "John"}, {"op": "delete", "field": "middlename"}]`), not nothing that is universally accepted. So yea, I get why "it doesn't seem to have gotten that famous", sadly.

Comment: @JoryGeerts - agree, and I believe that this is why it never got widespread acceptance, and if I'm honest, I tend to use it in whatever way is easiest for the data in question

Comment: For things that are essentially conventions, we spend an awful lot of time wringing our hands over them, especially considering how imperfect they are.  It reminds be a bit of the old chestnut "don't use tables for layout," even though they're used that way extensively in practice.  Perfectly good API's can be created entirely from GET and POST, and that actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some misunderstandings in your question.

> mydomain.com/v1/update-profile

*is* a resource. A URI *always* points to a resource. So a resource is not "part" of the URI, or something that needs an id. It is just something that can be accessed through a URI (whatever that is) and has some meaning.

Furthermore, it is not that `PUT` *is* idempotent, but *you have to make it that way* to comply with the [HTTP Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4).

You want to do that to make the life of your clients easier. What if the `POST` a client fires fails? The client will have to somehow deal with it, taking into account what it tried to achieve, possibly asking the server somehow if the operation still succeeded, etc. With `PUT`, the client can just fire it again and again until it succeeds. Much simpler to recover.

So yes, you should try to define the profile update to be a complete update, so you can offer `PUT`, if you can.